# Keep point colnames when I using sf::st_distance

Tags: r

I have a SpatailPointsDataFrame with ~5000 points (`df.pnt`),

```
head(df.pnt@data)
              Dim.1     Dim.2
point_174 -3.046076 0.9838644
point_175 -2.737621 1.2294271
point_176 -2.540366 1.3309294
point_177 -2.232753 1.4552122
point_179 -3.197286 0.9999750
point_180 -2.276608 1.7259754
```

I try to determine distance to each point to a line named `margin`,

```
margin
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -5.096744 ymin: -1.752608 xmax: 1.694162 ymax: 2.623441
CRS:           NA
                        geometry
1 MULTILINESTRING ((-4.641902...
```

using `sf::st_distance` function, such as

```
dist <- st_distance(st_as_sf(df.pnt), margin)
head(dist)
          [,1]
[1,] 0.2634273
[2,] 0.2518814
[3,] 0.3554745
[4,] 0.5927299
[5,] 0.1135675
[6,] 0.3539983
```

Problem, I loss the colnames information (as observed above with `head(df.pnt@data)`), which I need to keep the identity of each point when I calculate their distance from the margin!

Any suggestions to keep point colnames when I using `st_distance`, or any alternative functions suggested?

Comment: I don't know how to easily reproduce this example in my R session.  I did a test with a `sf` dataframe `df` and a `sf` `line` with where I add a column with `mutate` : 
 `df %>% dplyr::mutate(new_distance= st_distance(x=., y= line))` . It seems to work. Is it what you need?

Comment: Use either @VinceGreg suggestion, either use the fact, that length/number_of_rows of `dist` is the same as your `df.pnt` data frame. So `df.pnt$distance <- dist` will not hurt.